# Is it possible to create Amazon EKS cluster in other regions apart from us-west-2, us-east-1, eu-west-1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

From the below link,

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

Amazon EKS is available in the following Regions at this time:

US West (Oregon) (us-west-2)
US East (N. Virginia) (us-east-1)
EU (Ireland) (eu-west-1).

Is it possible to create AWS EKS cluster apart from this regions? Example, to deploy in us-west-1 or us-east-2.

I have created a terraform script to create the EKS cluster using existing VPCs. However, it fails with below error, I am trying to create the EKS cluster in us-west-1 region.

error creating EKS Cluster: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://eks.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/clusters: dial tcp: lookup eks.us-west-1.amazonaws.com on XX.XX.XX.XX:53: no such host

Answer (score 1):

No,  It is not possible. As EKS is a managed service, you cannot create a cluster of it is not available in that region.